# Can't save XDocument into Application Settings class

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, settings, ixmlserializable

I'm trying to use `IXmlSerializable` `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` methods with an `XDocument` object ( using the `Foo.WriteTo( ... )` and `XDocument.Load( ... )` methods.

I want to store the class which implements the `IXmlSerializable` interface into a variable stored within the default Application Settings class.

Trying to do this results in a pretty obnoxious failure :

[image]

This is the Settings class :

[image]

This is the class wrapping the

```
[Serializable]
class XmlModel : IXmlSerializable {
    public XDocument _foo = new XDocument(
        new XElement( "Foo",
            new XElement( "Bar", "Baz" ) ) );

    public XmlModel( XDocument Foo ) {
        _foo = Foo;
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema( ) {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml( XmlReader reader ) {
        this._foo = XDocument.Load( reader );
    }

    public void WriteXml( XmlWriter writer ) {
        _foo.WriteTo( writer );
    }
}
```

Aaaand this is the Program class ( I'm using just a simple console application to reproduce the issue )

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        if ( Settings.Default.DoUpgrade ) {
            Settings.Default.Upgrade( );
            Settings.Default.DoUpgrade = false;
            Settings.Default.Save( );
        }
        Console.WriteLine( Settings.Default.Foo._foo );
        Console.ReadLine( );
    }
}
```

This exception pops up because I have all exceptions turned on, but even with them OFF, the `ApplicationSettings` file isn't taking the data.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have to store such complex data in Settings? Why not use self-defined config file instead?

Comment: @LeiYang I'd rather keep the class within the application settings. It's how I've done it until now ( except for a change wherein the underlying data used to be stored separately but now is all stored in a single XDocument ). I don't know any better way to create an application config.

Comment: You've always doing the wrong way then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and Lei Yang was correct ( at least in the sense that I can't use XDocuments with Application Settings ).

According to the docs...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Output this <see cref="XElement"/> to an <see cref="XmlWriter"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">
    /// The <see cref="XmlWriter"/> to output the XML to.
    /// </param>
    public void Save(XmlWriter writer) {
        if (writer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        WriteTo(writer);
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
```

`XDocument.Save( )` calls `writer.WriteStartDocument( )`, which is apparently called further up in the `ApplicationSettings.Save( )` method, and since `XDocument.Save( ... )` cannot be overridden, I ( and by extension, everyone else who tried this ) will have to find another way.

### EDIT

Using an `XElement` instead of an `XDocument` allows it to be saved into an `ApplicationSettings` class :

```
[Serializable]
class XmlModel : IXmlSerializable {
    public XElement _foo = new XElement(
        "Foo", new XElement( "Bar", "Baz" ) );

    public XmlModel( XElement Foo ) {
        _foo = Foo;
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema( ) {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml( XmlReader reader ) {
        this._foo = XElement.Load( reader );
    }

    public void WriteXml( XmlWriter writer ) {
        _foo.WriteTo( writer );
    }
}
```